# How to PROPERLY inject Grails services using Spring resource.groovy

Tags: spring, grails, dependency-injection, resources, javabeans

Using Grails 2.2.1

I have the following Grails services defined:

```
package poc

class TestService {
    def helperService
}

class HelperService {
}
```

I have used the `TestService` as follow (`resources.groovy`):

```
test(poc.TestService) {
    
}

jmsContainer(org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer) {
    connectionFactory = jmsConnectionFactory
    destinationName = "Test"
    messageListener = test
    autoStartup = true
}
```

Everything works except for automatic injection of the `helperService`, as it is expected when the service create by Grails. The only way I can get it to work is to manually inject it as follow:

```
//added 
helper(poc.HelperService) {
}

//changed
test(poc.TestService) {
    helperSerivce = helper
}
```

The problem is that it is not injecting the same way as Grails does. My actual service is quite complex, and if I will have to inject everything manually, including all the dependencies.

Comment: Grails services are injected by default if appropriate nomenclature is used. You do not need entry in `resources.groovy` for services. What is the problem you are facing actuall?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Beans declared in `resources.groovy` are normal Spring beans and do not by default participate in autowiring. You can do so by setting the `autowire` property on them explicitly:

```
aBean(BeanClass) { bean ->
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
}
```

In your specific case, you don't need to define the `testService` bean in your `resources.groovy`, merely set up a reference to it from your `jmsContainer` bean like so:

```
jmsContainer(org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer) {
    connectionFactory = jmsConnectionFactory
    destinationName = "Test"
    messageListener = ref('testService') // <- runtime reference to Grails artefact
    autoStartup = true
}
```

This is documented in the ["Grails and Spring" section of the Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html) under "Referencing Existing Beans".

Comment: Also, autowiring by name will only be done on bean properties marked by `@Autowired` Spring annotation