# How is grails injecting beans of the class that is extending savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler without object injection

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security, dependency-injection

SuccessHandler:

```
class SuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler{
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                                        final Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request, response)
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl)
    }
    @Override
    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response) {
        boolean hasAdmin =SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted("ROLE_ADMIN");
        boolean hasUser=SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted("ROLE_USER");

        if(hasAdmin){
            return adminUrl;
        }else if (hasUser){
            return userUrl
        }else{
            return super.determineTargetUrl(request, response);
        }
    }
    private String adminUrl
    private String userUrl

    public void setAdminUrl(String adminUrl){
        this.adminUrl = adminUrl
    }

    public void setUserUrl(String userUrl){
        this.userUrl = userUrl
    }

}
```

Resources:

```
import successHandler.SuccessHandler

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    authenticationSuccessHandler(SuccessHandler) {
        adminUrl = '/admin/adminPanel'
        userUrl = '/'
    }
}
```

I want to know how is `adminUrl` and `userUrl` properties being injected though there are no any object created?

As far as I know , we should create an object for example `def authenticationSuccessHandler` .This creates the object with Autowired and then the object will be injected with the property defined in the resources bean.

But, here how is the property injected without any object being created??

Comment: Unsure if this helps but above is saying to your grails app : when you hit `SuccessHandler` use  `authenticationSuccessHandler` instead (overriding underying method) and whilst overriding set adminUrl and userUrl to be ... You are talking about injection which you typically do with services and this isn't a service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918967/how-to-properly-inject-grails-services-using-spring-resource-groovy

Comment: There is no any code to hit SuccessHandler . I did was just extended the spring security  success Handler class and it worked but i dont know how. Creating object  of SuccessHandler isn't necessary to call method determineTargetUrl() in the above class? well i didn't create a object for the class  but it worked. Any idea on how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982819/grails-spring-security-always-redirect-to-specific-page-after-login. I hope this answers your question. `SuccessHandler isn't necessary to call method determineTargetUrl() ` Success handler is doing its own thing or customly defined action. You are `overriding the defaults` in your resources.groovy. I think the question isn't really a question since you are confusing injection with overriding methods. You are injecting `authenticationSuccessHandler` over the default `SuccessHandler`

Comment: ` i didn't create a object for the class but it worked. Any idea on how` yes the plugin did the work and was working even before you made this change